# docker-composer volumes and networks have * or & in declaration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following configuration in my docker-compose file. What `*appvolume` means? I saw setups with `volumes: &appvolumes` as well.

```
version: "3"
services:
    ...
    setup:
       image: xxxx
       volumes: *appvolumes
       networks: *appnetworks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker-compose files use [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components) syntax. Those characters are YAML syntax for "anchors" and "aliaes", which are basically ways of referring to one section of the YAML document from another section of the document.  For example, consider this example:

```
example:
  list1: &foo
    - one
    - two
  list2: *foo
```

That defines an anchor named `foo` referring to the list in the `list1` key.  Elsewhere in the document we can use `*foo` to refer to that same list.

If you paste that into an [online yaml parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), you will find that the resulting data structures looks as if `list2` was specified with the same content as `list1`:

```
{
  "example": {
    "list1": [
      "one", 
      "two"
    ], 
    "list2": [
      "one", 
      "two"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is useful in a `docker-compose.yaml` file if you have a common set of volumes or networks, etc, that you want to include in several service definitions.

You can read more about this in the [Wikipedia YAML article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components).